# The optimal way of performing different side effects depending on whether the Validation is Success or Failure

Tags: scala, scalaz

I expect the solution not to be based on the obvious pattern matching of if-else. I'm sure there should be more natural ways to do it, like combination of `map` and `getOrElse` on Option.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Validation` has a `fold` method that can be co-opted to produce side effects:

```
v.fold(e => println("Ouch, we got "+e), a => println("Yay!!  We got "+a))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Validation.fold
```

Filling up answer with characters...

Comment: Instead of filling up the answer with meaningless characters, give an example on how to use the code you suggest.

Comment: The question creator didn't ask for an example.

Comment: This doesn't matter. SO is searching for the one, best answer, which does not only answer the question but gives explanations, examples etc - in best cases it should be possible to read an answer as a blog post, an article or as a book.

Comment: @user1296806 I think you should provide your own answer with your arguments in that case.

Answer (score 1):

For completeness, you may wish to operate on the Validation after side-effecting with it:

```
object Test {
  import scalaz._
  import syntax.bifunctor._
  import syntax.validation._
  def f(s: String) = { println(s"Err ${s}"); s }
  def g(i: Int) = { println(s"Int ${i}"); i }
  def m(x: Validation[String, Int]) = x bimap (f, g)
  def n(x: Validation[String, Int]) = f _ <-: x :-> g _
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val v = 17.success[String]
    val w = "nope".failure[Int]
    println(m(v) map (i => i + 1))
    println(m(v)); println(m(w))
    println(n(v)); println(n(w))
  }
}
```

Or, you maybe just like operators with faces.  Do emoticonic operators have a name in the functional community?  Given my present mood, I'd try emoperator, as in mope, but that may be too narrow.  Or "lolop"? But a usage like x :-> f is clearly a "facial expression."